# Can someone please explain how this was factored?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How was $x^2(x+1)-4(x+1)$ factored into $$(x^2-4)(x+1)?$$

I know this seems very basic but can someone please explain this?

Comment: It might be more clear if you use a substitution. Let $y = x+1$. Then, $x^2(x+1) - 4(x+1) = x^2y - 4y$, and now you can factor out a $y$ from both terms to get $x^2y - 4y = (x^2 - 4)y$. Finally, plug in $y = x+1$ to get $(x^2-4)y = (x^2-4)(x+1).$

Comment: $x^2$ bananas minus $4$ bananas is $(x^2-4)$ bananas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that in the original equation,
$$
x^2(x+1)-4(x+1)
$$
both the first and second term contain a $x+1$. So let's pull out the $x+1$. So we have 
$$
(x+1)(x^2-4)
$$
Moreover, notice the term on the right is a difference of perfect squares so the fully factored form is 
$$
(x+1)(x+2)(x-2)
$$

Comment: Wow, three answers seconds apart. +1 for going one step further.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. You're one (x+1) term short. Where did that term go?

Comment: @Anon Anything that two terms have in common, you can pull out. So if you have $x^2(x+1)-4(x+1)$, both the right and left terms have the **whole** $(x+1)$ term in common. So we pull out the entire thing, the whole $x+1$. So then you have $(x+1)(x^2-4)$. If you find this hard to believe, distribute to check, $(x+1)(x^2-4)=(x+1)x^2-(x+1)4=x^2(x+1)-4(x+1)$, which is what you started with. Of course, you could have distributed as $(x+1)(x^2-4)=x^3-4x+x^2-4$, which is the same thing you wrote originally if you distributed.

Comment: To extend this, if you had $x(x^3+x^2-1)-4(x^3+x^2-1)$, notice that the thing on the left and the thing on the right *both* have the same thing in parenthesis: $x^3+x^2-1$. So we can pull out that whole thing. So we move the entire thing, $x^3+x^2-1$ out front and write $(x^3+x^2-1)(\text{stuff})$, where stuff is what we have left that isn't $x^3+x^2-1$. But that's $x$ and a $-4$. So we have $(x^3+x^2-1)(x-4)$.

Comment: After that thorough explanation, I understand it now. Thank you so much. If you aren't a teacher or a tutor then you should be. Thanks again for taking time out of your day to explain it to me so well.

Comment: @Anon Thank you for your kind words. I do teach college Maths and tutor. It takes time to learn to see these tricks. Here it is easy to see how this factors because the thing in common is written in both terms. Most times, it takes a bit of work to see the 'stuff' in common between terms. For more practice with a bit harder problems that use this idea (often called factored by grouping) this is a decent site. But if it looks too confusing or not related to what you're doing, just ignore it. In any case, keep up the good work!

Comment: Here is the site:
http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Polynomials-and-rational-expressions/Factoring-by-Grouping-by-Rapalje.lesson

Answer (score 3):

From the distributive law,
$$(b + c)a = ba + ca$$
Choose $b = x^2$, $c = -4$ and $a = x + 1$.

Comment: Upvoted for you as well. $\mathrm{}\\$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the general case: $$ u \cdot y + v \cdot y. $$ We go backwards. We have from the distributive law that $$ (u+v) \cdot y = u \cdot y + v \cdot y, $$ by definition. Now, if $ u = x^2 $ and $ v = -4 $, you get the desired result.